# Is it possible to overwrite the PowerShell paste command?

Tags: powershell

According to https://superuser.com/posts/405858, to paste in PowerShell, we use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. I am wondering if it is possible to duplicate the Linux terminal paste command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Does PowerShell have a config file where we can manually set the shortcuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what version of PowerShell you have installed and whether you have the `PSReadLine` module installed.  `PSReadLine` provides support for custom key binds written in PowerShell, syntax highlighting and a bunch more.  If you are on Windows 10 (or Linux/Mac with PowerShell Core) it's installed by default.  If you're still on Windows 7 you need to upgrade to PowerShell 5.1 and install `PSReadLine` with this command:

```
Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser PSReadLine
```

and add the following to your profile:

```
Import-Module PSReadLine
```

Once you have PSReadLine installed you can set the shortcut to whatever you wish by putting this in your profile (note that this should be the default with PSReadLine installed anyway):

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'ctrl+v' -Function Paste
```

Or create a custom handler if you need to customize paste:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'ctrl+v' -BriefDescription CustomPaste {
    # Prepare clipboard
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Paste()
    # Finish
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly, not really sure what the custom handler is for but as of now I need the regular paste only. Thank you very much!